# How to select two MySQL rows and then compare a column and return an output

Tags: mysql

I've a table with a structure something like this,

```
Device | paid | time
abc       1    2 days ago
abc       0    1 day ago
abc       0    5 mins ago
```

Is it possible to write a query that checks the paid column on all the rows where `Device = abc` and then outputs the most recent two rows that different. Basically, something like an if statement saying if row 1 = 1 and row 2 = 0 output that but only if it's the most recent two columns that are different. For example, in this case, the first and second row. The table is being updated whenever a user changes from a free to paid account etc. It is also updated in different columns for different reasons hence the duplicate 0s for example.

I know this would probably be done better by having another table altogether and updating that every time the user switches account type, but is there any way to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: so you can simulate row_number in mySQL and partition by the device ordering by time descending which will give (from the above) the IDS 3,2,1  From this you could join the A.row_number + 1 = B.RowNumber which would allow you to compare row 1 and row 2 and row 2 and row 3 is this what you're after?

Comment: @xQbert would I be able to then return the two rows. I'm not awfully familiar with MySQL and its syntax tbh. I just know the basics and would usually have done something like this with a PHP if statement.

Comment: kinda depends is time a timestamp or is really 2 days 1 day 5 minutes etc.. is there a date/time on the table?

Comment: The time stamp is a date/time, the about 2 days, etc was just an example. Sorry, should have mentioned it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: 
http://rextester.com/MABU7860  need further testing on edge cases but this seems to work.

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM SQLfoo A
INNER JOIN SQLFoo B
 on A.Device = B.Device
and A.mTime < B.mTime
WHERE A.Paid <> B.Paid
  and A.device = 'abc'
ORDER BY B.mTime Desc, A.MTime Desc
LIMIT 1
```

By performing a self join we on the devices where the time from one table is less than the time from the next table (thus the two records will never matach and we only get the reuslts one way) and we order by those times descending, the highest times appear first in the result since we limit by a single device we don't need to concern ourselves with the devices.  We then just need compare the paid from one source to the paid in the 2nd source and return the first result encountered thus limit 1.

Or using user variables 
http://rextester.com/TWVEVX7830

in other engines one might accomplish this task by performing the join as in above, assigning a row number partitioned by the device and then simply return all those row_numbers with a value of 1; which would be the earliest date discrepency.

Comment: Perfect this works wonderfully. For a database like this where a user can go from paid to free and vice a versa would it be better to have a table dedicated to recording those changes rather than doing this type of command? So all you'd have to do then is select the most recent row using the device

Comment: I'm ill equipped to answer such a question.  I'd need to understand system alot better and requirements before I'd try to address: "is it better"  since better is subjective.  Better in what way? lines of code, design, performance maintenance....   If it works (test those edge cases), and meets performance expectations (you've tried this on hundreds/thousands/Millions? of records w/ proper indexes?) then I'd use it.  I personally think the join is sub-optimal as we join on = and < which gets us more records than we really want. What we really want is the next time record.

Comment: By edge cases take a look at this: http://rextester.com/FMK39002 are these the results you really want?  shoudl the 22nd' be returned or is the 27th acceptable since all the prior ones were the same paid value?  or would such a condition exists in the data does it only switch on "PAID" changes?

Comment: with regards to design... it depends on requirements.  From an audit/historical standpoint this design seems well suited to record events over time and provide traceablity.  If however all you ever need to know is if current system is paid or unpaid then we're recording alot of history for no reason.  But w/o knowledge of system requirements.  Not enough to say which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` to limit the number of record on mysql:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

In your case, use `LIMIT 2`

and then put the 2 record that you just select into an array, then compare the array if the value is different. If they are different then print

Comment: Not sure this works. If rows 2/3 are the first difference on paid and not 1/2 you've eliminated row 3 with the limit.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, accept it using the checkmark on the left. Happy coding :)

Comment: Can that be done in MySQL or would I have to do it outside of MySQL in PHP say?

Comment: So, in your case, you should select all the record, put them on an array, loop the array and then exit the loop and print if the value is different

Comment: I know but in my case, it's not possible. A friend has challenged me to do it using only MySQL and I want to see if it's even possible.

Comment: Yep it's possible

Comment: It is possible, you can declare variable, use if statement, loop in mysql query... but your query will look dirty and less readable.. But you said this is a challenge from your friend.. oh well

Comment: http://rextester.com/TWVEVX7830  is one way I'm working on a cleaner one that avoids user variables.  and need to test in greater detail the example w/ more edge cases.